# Remove duplicate words in the same cell within a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ms-word

i need somebody's help, i have a column with words, i want to remove the duplicated words inside each cell

what i want to get is something like this

| **words** | **expected** |
| --- | --- |
| car apple car good | car apple good |
| good bad well good | good bad well |
| car apple bus food | car apple bus food |

i've tried this but is not working

```
from collections import OrderedDict


df['expected'] = (df['words'].str.split().apply(lambda x: OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys()).str.join(' '))
```

I'll be very grateful if somebody can help me

Comment: Do you need to retain the original order of the words? If so, which duplicates should be removed - all but the first, all but the last?

Comment: Your solution output looks fine for me, why do you say not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to retain the original order of the words, you can create an intermediate set which will remove duplicates.

```
df["expected"] = df["words"].str.split().apply(set).str.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

If order is important use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) in a list comprehension:

```
df['expected'] = [' '.join(dict.fromkeys(w.split())) for w in df['words']]
```

output:

```
                words            expected
0  car apple car good      car apple good
1  good bad well good       good bad well
2  car apple bus food  car apple bus food
```

Answer (score 0):

if words are string "word1 word2":

```
df['expected'] = [" ".join(set(wrds.strip().split())) for wrds in df.words]
```